# Anti-concentration of Chi squared random variable

Tags: probability, inequality, probability-distributions, chi-squared

Most of the concentration bounds for chi squared are centered at it's mean.  I am wondering if there are known exponential bounds on the probability of being near zero, meaning
$
\mathbb{P}(\chi^2_k \leq \varepsilon \mathbb{E} \chi^2_k ) \leq ??
$

I have tried using the Payley-Zygmund inequality, but this only gives an inverse polynomial bound (in terms of k).

Comment: I guess one can frame the question as how small does $\varepsilon(k)$ have to be to get an exponential bound in $k$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function There is a Chernoff Bound for the CDF. Is it similar to what you want?

Comment: So, if you approximate the r.v. by a Gaussian with the right mean and variance (good approximation for large $k$) and use anticoncentration for Gaussians, do you get a sense of what you can hope for?